# is square bracket valid in xsl tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I want design something like...

```
<DB[0]><xsl:value-of select="test"><DB[0]>
```

which will update the database table field `DB[0]` with data test.
But it's not working ...as xsl is not allowing `[]` bracket.

Comment: Please provide an example. I can only guess what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to desing smthing like... <DB[0]><xsl:value-of select="test"><DB[0]> which will update the database table field DB[0] with data test. but its not working as xsl is nt allowing [] bracket...

Comment: As per the XML specification the square brackets are not allowed (if I read the spec correctly). You should use an attribute for the index which is much cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **In case you need to create a well-formed XML document**, then a string like "`<DB[0]>`" isn't a legal name.
2. **In case you want to create just text**, you can alwyas do so by specifying:

`<xsl:output method="text"/>`

So, **this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   &lt;DB[0]><xsl:value-of select="test"/>&lt;/DB[0]>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<test>XXX</test>
```

**produces**:

```
<DB[0]>XXX</DB[0]>
```

Comment: I want XML document and not text. is there any way to do <DB"0">xxx</DB"0"> and then replace DB"0" with DB[0] ?

Comment: @Manoj: No, neither `<DB"0">xxx</DB"0">` nor  `<DB[0]>XXX</DB[0]>` is wellformed XML. I'd say both of them don't have even close similarity to XML. A name in XML cannot contain the `[` or the `]` character.

Answer (score 1):

**XML element Naming Conventions**

- Names can contain any [alphanumeric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric)
  character, but must not start with a
  number or punctuation character.
- Names cannot contain spaces.
- Names must not start with the letters xml, as they could be easily confused with an XML document definition.
- Do not use ":" characters within element names.

For exact definition, please visit [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#sec-common-syn).

So either '[' or ']' is not allowed.